# General approach to find a function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, education

Is there a particular way to find a function using given conditions

> If f(x) is a differentiable function satisfying $f^2
> (x) + f^2
> (y) + 2(xy – 1) = f^2
> (x + y) $
> , Also
> f(x) > 0
> $f  (\sqrt2)= 2$

I can only see a symmetry in $f^2
(x) + f^2
(y) + 2(xy)$.......$€(a+b)^2$
But I dont know how exactly should I approach such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(t)=f^2(t)$, which is also differentiable.
Plug in $x=y=0$ to find $2g(0)-2=g(0)$, i.e.,
$$g(0)=2. $$
Now shift terms around
$$ g(x+y)-g(x)=g(y)+2(xy-1)=g(y)-g(0)+2xy$$
and divide by $y$ (assuming $y\ne 0$):
$$ \frac{g(x+y)-g(x)}y = \frac{g(y)-g(0)}y+2x.$$
Taking the limit as $y\to 0$, we recognize derivatives:
$$ g'(x) = g'(0) +2x.$$
From this, we infer by integration
$$g(x)=xg'(0)+x^2+C$$
for some constant $C$.
We know $g(0)=2$ and $g(\sqrt 2)=4$, so must have $C=2$ and $g'(0)=0$.
Hence ultimately,
$$ f(x)=+\sqrt{g(x)}=\sqrt{x^2+2}.$$

---

**Remark:** We did not really need the given property $f(x)>0$.